# What is the maximum number of contracts Cardano can store?

Tags: smart-contract, blockchain, ledger

I see Ethereum (ETH) can store 2<sup>256</sup> smart contracts, so is there any description about this for Cardano, i.e. how many contracts can Cardano store?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Cardano, the smart contractors are submitted as transactions with a validator script. Funds locked in the smart contract are in UTXO with the address as the "Script Address". And based on three parameters called datum, redeemer, and context, the validator script provides the go-ahead for the release of funds.

Based on this setting theoretically, there is **no limit to the number** of deployable smart contracts since there is no limit on how many transactions can be submitted to the blockchain. The size of Datum, which can carry some bit of data, is yet to be promulgated.

Comment: Thank you, pro!

Comment: I don't really understand the answer. Since each smart contract corresponds to an address, and the number of bits that encode an address is fixed, and even the number of bits used to encode the hash of the datum is fixed, the number of smart contracts should be fixed, and I don't know what happens when there is a hash collision.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question. 2^256 what?

To my knowledge, the maximum size of a smart contract on ETH is 24 KB. According to the [Cardano Foundation](https://medium.com/cardanorss/how-to-get-started-with-metadata-on-cardano-8380bbe25103), the maximum transaction metadata size is 16 KB. Since smart contracts are not yet deployed, I'm not sure what the size limitation will be but, it will probably be in this ball park.

Comment: thank for your answer, but I mean how many contracts Cardano can store, not the contract size.

Comment: @RongNguyen if a blockchain gets close to the limit, the developers will certainly adjust it to increase the limit or remove it altogether. A blockchain cannot function if it is "full".