# What are technical differences in smart contract execution on Cardano in comparison to Ethereum?

Tags: smart-contract, transaction, blockchain, ethereum, eutxo

In my understanding, smart contracts on Cardano are always provided to the blockchain via a transaction and there is no code that is stored at the blockchain, but just a hash (the public key address). Ethereum seems to store them instead: see [What is the maximum number of contracts Cardano can store?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/140/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-contracts-cardano-can-store) 
Is this correct?

**What are the other main technical differences?**

**Update**
Also beyond that Cardano uses the eUTxO-based model and Ethereum uses an account-based model.

Answer (score 4):

Feel free to improve! :)

| technical aspect | Cardano | Ethereum | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| model | eUTxO-based | account-based | [see cardano lecture](https://youtu.be/igV7kMXcdpw), [see question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/696/eutxo-transaction-model-vs-account-based-transaction-model), ... |
| smart contract code location | not stored on-chain, but shipped with transaction | stored on-chain **?** |  |
| smart contract maximum count | unlimited | limited **?** | [see question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/140/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-contracts-cardano-can-store) |
| access third party contract e.g. an oracle | import and use lib (required or just helpful?), , compile your own contract, ship third party validator script with transaction, ... | call it via an address **?** | [see question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/702/referencing-onchain-contract-as-3rd-party/721#721) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to complement @JohannesSirsch answer.

One of the most important aspects of any network, when working with smart contracts, is the ability of the script to see the ***"event horizon"***:

- In Bitcoin, all the script sees is the Redeemer that contains all the logic necessary to verify Tx.
- In Ethereum, the script sees the whole blockchain, and that's not good regarding security.
- In Cardano, the script sees all the Tx-ins and Tx-outs, including Redeemer.

Answer (score 1):

This video lecture in the Plutus Pioneers Program explains it https://youtu.be/igV7kMXcdpw